# Facebook API no works

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to obtain the most updated metrics with the **since** and **until** parameters, but when I indicate the date and time (as I have done before and the API response) it comes out empty and if I put the next day I get the data. I don't understand this behavior:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the same parameters in both API calls, the only thing I change is the since and until parameters

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v12.0) state that the `since` and `until` parameters must have the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

You are not obtaining any results from the second request because the you supply a datetime format (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+Z)` instead of the date format.

Try to change these values and retry the request.